# Python open a url and extract location.href value from 'onclick'

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, onclick

Here is the inspect element from a url "https://www.example.com":

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-click" onclick="location.href='https://d3.net/archive/123.mp4'"></button>
```

I want to write a script to open the above url (https://www.example.com), and then extract this 'https://d3.net/archive/123.mp4' from 'onclick'.

What should I do?

Comment: The element you have posted is that returned from your soap object?

Comment: @KunduK It is from the url when right-click and click on inspect.

Comment: If this rendered by java-script bs4 can't help you in that case.You need to use browser tool like selenium.Post your url if this public?

Comment: Just print this to check if you are getting any element or `None`. `print(soup.select_one("button.btn.btn-click[onclick]"))`

Comment: @KunduK I tried to print this as you suggested and got None. My url is not public, it needs username and password, but I already logged in when I run the code...Do i have to include codes for dealing with username and password to make "requests.get(url)" works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on links like this I recommend a different approach:

use  [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

No `re` module needed then.

### Update 1 for debugging

If you want to see the soup you get for your request you can either do that here (see comment `#DEBUG1`) or in the code example below (`#DEBUG3`) to see what you get as ingredients for your soup, see `#DEBUG2` in the code example below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#DEBUG1 print the soup. 
# import sys
# print >> sys.stderr, soup.prettify() # python2.X
print(soup.prettify) # python3.X

# select button with location href at the beginning (you can add the class as well)
for item in soup.select("button[onclick^=\"location.href=\"]"):
    # ... do stuff here, e.g.
    onclick = item["onclick"]
    href = onclick.split("=")[1]

    # now href is 'https://d3spcaxyl0it1f.cloudfront.net/archive/123.mp4'
    href = href.strip("'")

    # the leading and trailing ' are gone.
    if href.endswith(".mp4"):
        # do stuff here or precise your css selector further
        # ...
```

Why should you use that approach? 
To ensure your button does indeed have the requested attributes.

Why is that a good thing?
Because you do not need to check for the existence of the attribute by using `item.get('onclick')` first and then act based on that decision.

How do you get the page into your soup? (Direct quote from [@akore128](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8407652/akore128) )

```
# import sys
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get('http://www.example.com') 
#DEBUG2
# print >> sys.stderr, page.text # python2.X
print(page.text) # python3.X

# Create a BeautifulSoup object 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#DEBUG3 print the soup. 
# print >> sys.stderr, soup.prettify() # python2.X
print(soup.prettify) # python3.X
```

Comment: However, when I include "verify=False" into "requests.get('<url>')", the errors disappeared, but I got nothing. It meant that `print(href)` does not work. 
What should I do? Do i have to include codes for dealing with username and password to make `requests.get('<url>')` works?

Comment: In that case please add this information to your question as further answers should take that into account. If you need to pass user and password to the site that is a hell of a difference in means of "how to get the soup from a access restricted page". Please ask a second question for that topic as "how to retrieve specific data from a soup" has nothing to do with the other topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Navigate to the URL
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
# Find all links matching our XPATH
elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-click']")
# Iterate the element list
for element in elements_list: 
    # Extract the onClick attribute value
    onclick_attr_value = element.get_attribute("onclick")
    # Match regex to capture the URL only
    match = re.search("'(.*)'", onclick_attr_value)
    if match:
        # If the regex matched, Bingo!
        found_url = match.group(1)
        print(found_url)
```